# I'm trying to keyframe (animate) the "fac" of a material's transparency to gradually appear it but doesnt work

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to animate the appearance of an object gradually, a simple one like is was a ghost or something similar. I should say that I'm doing this while I'm working with post-rendering, I'm using "pass indexs" and ID mask for the object (not the material).

For the material of object A I have a simple node like emission and transparency connected to a mix shader. I saw a couple of videos that if I keyframe the "fac" of the mix shader mentioned above, it will do it gradually, but it wont. When I do it, before 0.5, let's say 0.4999... it completely materialized, when is 0.5000001.... or above, it's completely gone.
Even thought in the Graph editor **there is a curve** for the materials' shader's "fac", it doesn't behave that way.

It there any other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: factor is between 0.0-1.0 so 0.5 is less than 100% and 5.00001 is well over 100%.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: *"simple node like emission and transparency connected to a mix shader"* so from this explanation looks like you're using Cycles. However question is tagged with Blender Render old engine. Which one do you use? I'm not sure what is "post-rendering" as well. Some screenshots would help understand your project